# JavaScript - PopUp Window With Text When Clicking List Items

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing with the script below. My goal is to have an ordered list (per assignment requirements), where a pop up window with text comes up when any of the list items are clicked. Each list item would lead to different text.

I know there may be more efficient ways to do this, which are out of the scope of my understanding at this point, so I'm trying to do the following [non-working] work-around below.

Example: When the user clicks the "One" list item, a pop up window should appear with the text inside it saying "Item 1", but I get "undefined" as a result. Any tips?

My test HTML:

```
<ol id="javaList" onclick="popUp()">
    <li value="Item 1">One</li>
    <li value="Item 2">Two</li>
    <li value="Item 3">Three</li>
</ol>
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script>

    window.popUp = function() {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=200");
        var ls = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        myWindow.document.write(ls.value);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code.

You don't need to have the width and height in quotes, and you can capture the element with [the event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) from your onclick handler. Your `window.popup` function should be:

```
<script>
window.popUp = function(event) {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", 400, 200);
    var ls = event.currentTarget;
    myWindow.document.write(ls.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: See my solution as well; you can't get a value of an `li`.  So the last line should look something like `myWindow.document.write(ls.getAttribute('data-value'));` where the HTML is modified to replace `value` with `data-value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the `value` of an `li` it returns `0` in every case.  Try changing it to `data-value` instead.

If you are including the jQuery library, the solution becomes trivial.  Your HTML would become:

```
<ol id="javaList">
    <li data-value="Item 1">One</li>
    <li data-value="Item 2">Two</li>
    <li data-value="Item 3">Three</li>
</ol>
```

And JavaScript would become:

```
$('li').on('click', function(event){
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=200");
    myWindow.document.write($(this).data('value'));
}
```